# MVC is for applications or Objects

Tags: model-view-controller

so im just starting out in web development and have spent hours trying to ensure i have the basics down. It's surprising how much confusion exists on the subject. Anyways I've decided to take the time to outline a couple things in this post. I do so with the hopes that I will receive feedback from the community to further clarify and streamline my understanding of the subject. Today's post is on the subject of MVC and specifically what MVC is and what it's describing.

the name is MVC - which stands for Model, View and Controller... Should it not be Models, Views and Controllers? That is from an application level view the MVC pattern outlines a practice of separating all activities of the application into Models, Views and Controller Objects. Each object being completely independent from the others and capable of being combined or utilized in any number of ways.

This business of Model, View and Controller vs Models, Views and Controllers gives the idea that the pattern can be applied to a single Object. Granted doing so would most likey produce three distinct objects in the process. Otherwise why is it not Models, Views and Controllers... you see what im getting at?

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at.  Is your question really about the pluralisation of the label that the pattern is given?  This is the *least* important piece of understanding you will ever need.  I can suggest two possible reasons for the name (neither of which makes any meaningful difference).  One, that each piece of functionality in your application be represented by *a* model, *a* view and *a* controller - there is no requirement that an MVC application contain more than one of each.  Two: that "model view controller" is more pleasing to say and to hear than "models views controllers."

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow - your question can be boiled down to one sentence "Why do we say Model-View-Controller and not Models-Views-Controllers, since applications will frequently have many" :)

Comment: `I've decided to take the time to outline a couple things in this post` are you cross-posting your blog posts to SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the name Model-View-Controller, describes a paradigm rather than an actual set for of files or objects. So the Model-element isn't a single file, but multiple files grouped under function of being the application's model.

In the below picture you can see an illustration of how the the different elements of a MVC can contain multiple sets of logic.[image: MVC]

This is kind of a abstract subject, so not as easy to explain. I would recommend watching Paul Hegarty's, a Standford professor, lecture on MVCs [here](https://itunesu.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/LZDirectory.woa/ra/directory/courses/593208016/feed). [Source](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller-03.png)

Hope I understood what you where asking for.

Answer (score 2):

MVC is an example of a ["design pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern), which is a way of communicating an approach to a problem. The patterns are singular, but you may use many patterns while putting together an application.

As a commenter noted, the grammatical structure of a pattern's name is the least important thing to understand! Instead, understand that patterns provide a great shorthand for communicating potentially complex ideas. For example, I might add some methods to a class and describe them as "preventing duplicate instances", but if instead I mention "this class follows the [Singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) pattern", I've made it clearer what the intention is.

Comment: right, thanks... then i would be correct in assuming that there is a great deal of overlap between the concepts of software architecture patterns and design patters. And one could equally call MVC a "design pattern" and/or a software architecture pattern?